# My bettercap doesn’t show all the devices connected to my network

Tags: bettercap

I am running bettercap on a Linux virtual machine and when I type the command `net.probe` doesn’t show any device or ip and when I type `net.show`,
it only shows three IP addresses that all are from my router.

Can anyone help me solve this issue?

Comment: welcome - you need to provide some more info before this q can even be answered - ie. how does the vm connect to the network? what about the host? (also, at this point it looks like a straight-up networking q, so off topic and will likely be moved - in either case the extra info will likely be required)